# Rest-Api using Jersey showing MessageBodyWriter Error

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am new to REST-API and building an application using Jersey.while running it on server
I get the following error :

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<com.jersey.test.aman.model.Message>.
```

Following is my main code.

```
@XmlRootElement
@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {

    MessageService ms = new MessageService();

    @GET
    //Produces is the response type 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Message> getMessage(@BeanParam MessageFilterBean 
            msgFilterBean){
        if(msgFilterBean.getYear() > 0){
            return ms.getAllMessageForYear(msgFilterBean.getYear());
        }
        return ms.getAllMessages();
    }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `@XmlRootElement` shouldn't be on the resource class. It should be on the root model class, i.e. the `Message` class.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet . It works now. :)